# Have changed content of file, but in web browser the new content appears only after some minutes. Where to set cache time CentOS php?

Tags: centos, php

Using WinSCP and Notepad++ changed content of php file. Save.

Then in web browser open the changed file. But see previous content. The changed (new) content appears only after ~3 minutes.

Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1581067/2465936 found related question. And answer that it is related with cache time. So as understand need to change cache time? Where to change? Suppose in php.ini? What to change? Tried to reduce `session.cache_expire = 180` but no solution.

May be it is because of Varnish http://www.servermom.com/install-varnish-3-to-run-with-apache-2-on-centos-server/552/ ? May be to try to uninstall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of Varnish program. Possibly need change configuration.
Or can uninstall

`yum remove varnish`

Then edit httpd.conf (change ports to 80)

Then `service httpd restart`